# Are there any official adventures for non-werewolf shapeshifters?

Tags: published-adventures, world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

I've recently picked up several breedbooks for Werewolf: The Apocalypse. While there appear to be many adventures for werewolves, I'm wondering if there are any intended for use by non-Garou changing breeds.

Although I could modify the Garou-based adventures for use by other changing breeds, I would prefer to use something that already incorporates that breed's themes, if it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TLDR: Not Exactly...

The Fera was never the *real* driver for World of Darkness, and a lot was written Garou-centric. However, there are rare examples where Fera was used to a bigger degree than usual, though they never had a published adventure book *on their own*.

Often enough, a few appear on the sidelines of larger Garou Adventure books. Among the published adventures, *Rage Across the Amazon* contains a full adventure that might be the easiest to adapt for a very small subset of Fera. And then there's *Midnight Circus*, a WoD Kitchen Sink.

### Ahadi

The *Breedbook: Bastet* was the first that contained the setting of the Ahadi, which contains some Garou (Silent Striders), but is otherwise entirely Fera. It contains a rough rundown of the formation, and some storyteller hints at how to run such a formation campaign.

*Players Guide to the Changing Breeds* also contains an Ahadi chapter, that contains at least some possible adventure hooks in the "Recent Events" chapter. But don't be fooled, that's one of the few redeeming qualities of the otherwise not-very-good book. There are some pointers for a Blacktooth-Rule or Ahadi-Founding campaign in the W20 *Changing Breeds* book in "Appendix One: Ahadi".

*Rage Across Egypt* also has a chapter on the Players of the Ahadi in the area, and some story seeds, though no full campaign.

For more pointers to flesh out the campaign's landscape, refer to *A World of Rage*, chapter "Africa and the Middle East". A travelogue that might inspire campaign arches can be found in W20 *Rage across the world*, chapters "Cairo", "Francistown, Botswana" and "Tanzania and Kenya". The W20 *Book of the Wyrm* contains a few Africa-specific monstrosities, which could show up in your campaign.

### Beast Courts

*Hengeyokai: Shapeshifters of the East* was the Asian Werewolf setting, and is meant to play with only Stargazers and Hakkan (Shadow Lords) and a few of the other Fera (Mokolé, Nagah, Khan, Kitsune, Ratkin, Rokea). It doesn't contain a full *campaign* but pointers on how to run a game there.

*Players Guide to the Changing Breeds* also contains a Beast Court chapter, but it is vastly inferior to Hengeyokai. There's just a hint of guidance for a Hengeyokai campaign in the W20 *Changing Breeds* book, *Appendix Two: Hengeyokai*.

For more pointers to flesh out the campaign's landscape, refer to *A World of Rage*, chapter "India and Asia". Some adventures might be inspired by the log entries from W20 *Rage across the World*, chapters "Shanghai" and "Central Asia". The Kuei-Jin (the *Shapeshifters of the East* series) supplements that describe Asia after dark include some pointers to how the Beast Courts operate and might be an inspiration for a campaign fighting the servants of the Yama Kings.

### Jaguars of War!

*Rage Across the Amazon* is less a campaign and more a location book, but the Amazon basin's Fera forces make up about half as many members as all the Garou that went there. They might be somewhat disorganized and loners because they are Balam and Mokolé, but a campaign could take the hooks and campaign notes without a change. It'd be mostly a ragtag group of them.

The notes of "Chapter Four: Encounters" can be run entirely without the background of Garou going there for war. Only the short campaign "Rio by Night" presented there doesn't easily work for such a group. "In Dreams and Nightmares" might even be easier for a group that stems from the Amazon Basin. Just putting in a Spirit, personal Totem, elder Balam, or Mokolé as the replacement for the Garou sept leaders that give orders can work.

> Otherwise, you might use Kinfolk as informants that point to the target or persons that could be compromised for smaller encounters.
> During "In Dreams and Nightmares", Day Three might be much easier with at least one Balam to deal with diplomacy and a Mokolé that deals with a river.

### The End Times Campaign implements them

*Time of Judgement: Apocalypse* contains the Scenario "Weaver Ascendent", which heavily features a Japanese Corporation. It can be easily used in a Fera or Hengeyokai game, there are even Storyteller boxes on how to use Fera and Sections on both the Beast Courts and Ahadi.

> It's possibly even easier to use Fera and Hengeyokai, as the corp is fighting mostly Garou and ignored the much less aggressive Hengeyokai.

Likewise, the "Ragnarök" section contains lots of hints on how to handle a more Fera-centric game in the scenario.

### In other times, Fera play major roles!

W20 *Shattered Dreams* is an anthology of adventures that are technically Garou centered, but which heavily feature Fera in some, and where at times cooperation of Fera and Garou is more normal in these other timelines since the War of Rage was averted or not as bad.  If you are up to playing AU adventures, those could be integrated into a Fera game somewhat seamlessly.

### There's a splat independent sourcebook for a true Menagerie

*Midnight Circus* is a campaign/setting supplement that is set up in such a way that it can be run by **any** WoD Splat, even in a mixed group. It's rather old and stats might need polishing, but it has reasons for *any* group to try and do *something* there. Whatever your group is made from, you can easily tinker with this book to turn it into a campaign arch that matches your group. It's a veritable *Kitchen Sink* that doesn't even need adaption, but the book has a few problems: it's less of a campaign with scenes but more a location to fling at your group.

Comment: +1 for *Midnight Circus*. It's probably the best example of trying to dump everything from the WoD in a single supplement. Whether that succeeds or not is another question...

Answer (score 0):

There is Hengeyokai (sp), changing breeds of the East and there's books for Bastet (cats) Corax (crow), and all the other changing breeds in the WoD.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: As I said in the question, I already have some of the changing breed books. I am looking for published adventures specific to those breeds. For example, is there a published adventure featuring rokea pcs?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. It only lists different changing breeds, not adventures for them.